# Custom ASPX Form whats the better way

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have developed a portal using SharePoint 2010 (Standard Edition). I want to develop a Master-Detail "Requisition" form using Visual Studio 2010. I don't want users to access the List and click on "Add New" to access the form. I want to create a link on portal's homepage like "Requisition Form" when user will click on the link it should open the form right there.

Should I create a Visual WebPart ..then create new page and embed the webpart there? or should I develop WebPart Page..I've never done webpart page so what's the better approach? and to Edit the page do I need to create another Visual part with Gridview control and fill currently logged in user's Requisitions including Item ID and pass it on to MyCustomRequisitionEditForm.aspx ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you customize standard new form of the list with Sharepoint Designer or InfoPath? You can create a link to this form on the homepage of your portal.

Comment: cannot customize as i have master detail form and so much code behind to control certain fields..plus i cant use infopath..using standard edition of sharepoint.